# Rounding up a number to nearest 1 in django template

Tags: django

I am having a hard time trying to do some simple math inside my django template with mathfilters, i divide the number by 12, and then multiply it with 1.18, for this i use the following formula:

```
{{coffee.orderedQuantity|div:12000|mul:1.18}}
```

Which works fine, but it returns a decimal number, which i would like to alway be rounded up, so if the decimal is 1.2342 it should show as 2 in my template.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated :)

Comment: The answer was very helpful, thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `|floatformat`

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

```
{% with rest = coffee.orderedQuantity|div:12000|mul:1.18 %}
{% if rest == rest|floatformat:"0" %}
    {{rest}}
{% else %}
    {% rest = rest|add:1 %}
    {{rest}}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two different ways to get the desired result.

First, Use [floatformat](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#floatformat), Like this :

```
{{ coffee.orderedQuantity|div:12000|mul:1.18|floatformat:"0" }}
```

Or, you can make a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/). Custom template tag can be used repeatedly for further purposes and most recommended method.